# Wordpress — переадресация по url на другой шаблон single-{post_type}-{other}.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть custom_post_type = "post_type"
Есть шаблон вывода записи ="single-post_type.php"

Необходимо, что бы при переходе по ссылке mywebsite.com/post_type/post_name/second подгружался не single-post_type.php, а например single-post_type-second.php.

При этом необходимо сохранить single-post_type.php.

**Готов заплатить (300р-500р), за объяснение** Вами предложенного Вами же рабочего решения. На сбер или киви.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил с помощью [template_include](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/)

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_post_type_second' );
function include_post_type_second( $template ) {
if ( (in_array('second', explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))) ) {
if ( $new_template = locate_template( array( 'single-post_type-second.php' ) ) )
$template = $new_template ;
}
return $template;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну так создайте файл `single-$posttype-$slug.php` согласно иерархии шаблонов Wordpress, где $posttype - зарегистрированный тип поста, $slug - его слэг (у вас, видимо, это "second"). Никаких дополнительных действий по настройке переадресации и т. д. не требуется

[image: WordPress template hierarchy]

Comment: Это я пробовал среди первых вариантов. Не работает.